# How to round to the nearest whole number and convert to percentage

Tags: r, tibble

I want to convert these into a whole number and then turned into percentages.
For example, exam one, 0.318 being turned into 32 marks, that then creates a column saying '32%', or a column that displays the percentage marker i.e. 0-9, 10-19 ... 90-99

```
> exam_results_stats <- 
 tibble(exam_one = runif(1:10), exam_two = runif(1:10), exam_three =
 runif(1:10), exam_four = runif(1:10), exam_five = runif(1:10),
 exam_six = runif(1:10))

exam_results_stats[, 1:6]
   exam_one exam_two exam_three exam_four
      <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
 1   0.318    0.225      0.432     0.915 
 2   0.0747   0.0854     0.217     0.879 
 3   0.327    0.188      0.211     0.582 
 4   0.260    0.593      0.754     0.427 
 5   0.0569   0.172      0.519     0.258 
 6   0.175    0.721      0.395     0.740 
 7   0.0530   0.414      0.924     0.919 
 8   0.486    0.670      0.491     0.894 
 9   0.566    0.891      0.786     0.868 
10   0.466    0.762      0.0480    0.0377
```

Comment: Well what do you really want? A column with ``XX%`` or a column with [0,9], [10,19] ... ?

Comment: Now that I think about it, a single column with ```XX%``` would only work if I were to collect the mean of rows across the entire columns, otherwise, I would have to create furthermore columns with '%'. So, a column that suggests just that along with one with [0,9] ...

Answer (score 1):

First you can write a function using `paste0` and `round`. It's helpful to wrap this in `format` so that the correct number of decimal places will always be displayed. Then you can use `lapply` to apply this function to all of your columns.

```
fxn <- function(x) {
  format(paste0(round(x * 100, 0), "%"), nsmall = 2)
}

exam_results_stats[1:6] <- lapply(exam_results_stats[1:6], fxn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` and some base R

```
exam_results_stats <- tibble(
      exam_one = runif(1:10),  exam_two = runif(1:10), 
      exam_three = runif(1:10),  exam_four = runif(1:10), 
      exam_five = runif(1:10), exam_six = runif(1:10))

exam_results_stats %>%
  mutate_all(function(x) paste0(as.character(round(x*100, digits= 0)),"%"))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
exam_one exam_two exam_three exam_four exam_five exam_six
<chr>    <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   
  1 87%      34%      61%        58%       65%       96%     
  2 49%      84%      18%        26%       92%       48%     
  3 28%      33%      16%        74%       4%        5%      
  4 2%       43%      16%        21%       98%       95%     
  5 4%       30%      16%        97%       57%       58%     
  6 1%       23%      21%        20%       31%       37%
```

Note: your data is now non-numeric, it needs to be converted back to a numeric data type if you wish to operate on it mathematically or plot it